# What's the ID of monster spawners in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know the ID of monster spawners is 52, but how to make it show different mobs? It's either 52:0 or 52-0 or something like that.

Comment: May I ask what you intend to do with the ID once you have it? Minecraft PE does not yet have any commands implemented, making it a fairly useless bit of information afaik.

Comment: I have a server and I want to fill in a big square with spawners. On my server there are commands. And when i use `/fill area 52` It shows me a blank spawner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 0):

This command will place a mob spawner that spawns an entity of your choice.

```
/setblock x y z mob_spawner replace {EntityId:id}
```

- **x, y, and z** are the coordinates where you want to place the spawner.
- **id** is an entity ID. You can find a list of them in the [Minecraft Wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values/Entity_IDs).

Examples:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ mob_spawner replace {EntityId:58}      
     places an Enderman spawner at your location

/setblock 4 20 -289 mob_spawner replace {EntityId:Zombie}
     places a Zombie spawner at the coordinates (4, 20, -289)
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. For example wool in mcpe is `35`. Orange wool is `35:1`  So I thought with spawners it would be the same, `52,` a colon and a number stating the type! But that didn't work!

Comment: @TikoluX Spawners don't use damage values like this to differentiate between types of spawner. You have to set the NBT.