# Minecraft Command Troubles

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been playing the Bedrock version of Minecraft on Switch and I'm trying to get a lever that can only be placed on a gold block this is what I entered in the command block:

```
/give @p lever 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["Block_of_Gold"]}
```

After that it just says

> Line 1 Column 2 Missing '}' or object member name

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's not called "Block_of_Gold". Look at the wiki for block ID names.

Answer (score 1):

As Fabian pointed out, the name for “Block of Gold” isn’t `Block_of_Gold`, it’s `gold_block`. Bedrock Edition uses JSON format, not NBT, so the command would be:

```
/give @p lever 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["gold_block"]}}
```

See [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/334104/188492) for more information on using `"can_place_on"`.

Source: [Block of Gold on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Gold)