# How do you enchant a stick in Minecraft Bedrock Edition version 1.9?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to enchant a stick in Minecraft Bedrock Edition version 1.9?

Comment: Have you tried reaching this yourself?   To the best of my knowledge you need commands to enchant a stick, as you cannot enchant it in an enchanting table.

Comment: Duplicate of the standard Bedrock NBT questions, [How do I use an NBT editor to modify item properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/how-do-i-use-an-nbt-editor-to-modify-item-properties), and, [How do I give a player an item with custom properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374643/250180)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/enchant):

> Although `/enchant` enforces maximum levels and compatibility, other commands (such as `/give`, `/replaceitem`, and `/data`) can bypass these restrictions.

However, the `give` and `replaceitem` commands only support the JSON tags `can_place_on` and `can_destroy`. [See this for more information on that.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/334104/188492) The `data` command isn't available in Bedrock Edition/Pocket Edition.

Answer (score 1):

You can mod any enchantment using the Minecraft Universal Editor. The easiest way is to put a enchanted sword and the not enchanted stick in a chest. Go into the Editor, search the chest and copy the enchantment over to your stick. I did it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do a can_place_on or can_destroy:

```
/give @p iron_pickaxe 1 0 {¨can_destroy¨:{¨blocks¨:[¨minecraft:coal_ore¨]}}
```

That would give you an iron pickaxe that could break coal in adventure mode. You could also do:

```
/give @p deadbush 1 0 {¨can_place_on¨:{¨blocks¨:[¨minecraft:grass¨]}}
```

That would give you a deadbush that you can place on grass in adventure mode.

Answer (score -1):

idk in im minecraft switch 1.16.221 rn. maybe hold a stick and try:
/enchant @p knockback (level of enchantment

Examples of enchants: (Hold item to enchant)
(Player holds diamond boots) /enchant blast_protection 2 (Boots gets blast protection II)

So maybe try holding a stick and try doing: /enchant knockback 1000

Or try this if not working: /enchant knockback_1000

Im not sure how it works tho

Comment: no, just no. this is wrong, the other answers are correct.