# How do you get custom heads in Minecraft for Switch?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I would like to use a custom head in Minecraft for Switch, like you can for the Java version of the game. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, Dustin! Welcome to Arqade. I’m not really sure what you’re asking about, could you please clarify?

Comment: Why was this put on hold? Is there a different way to understand this question than "You can create custom player heads in the Java edition, how do I do it in the switch edition?"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Comment: @FabianRöling that post doesn't seem related to this one at all... Sounds like a custom skin question, but perhaps I'm mistaken about what an NBT tag is?

Comment: @Tim NBT is everything in curly brackets, a way to set almost all properties of items, blocks and entities. It does not exist in MCPE, therefore the commands there are very limited.

Comment: This isn't MCPE, although I'd expect console version to have similar limitations. Regardless, if the answer is "no, you can't do that on the Switch", then that's far different than it being a duplicate question based on using a command. In the PC/Java version, you can do so via textures without using a single /command.

Comment: The specified duplicate makes 0 sense as a duplicate. The reason this is impossible has absolutely **nothing** to do with wether you can use NBT tags or not, the fact is that Player Skulls are not a feature in the first place.

Comment: If you're looking to be the last close voter, please don't. Read my comment above. NBT isn't even the base reason you can't do this, it's simply that a feature like this doesn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

There is currently no way to get a custom player head in the nintendo switch version that works like the java version.

You could use a custom resource pack on a home brewed system to change the textures of the mob head. I advise against this unless you know what you are doing!

Comment: Note that instead of this home brewed stuff - you can just use a normal resource pack not really sure what that guy was talking about