# Minecraft PE, help me make a command to give me a multishot crossbow?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

Im trying to make a command that gives me a crossbow with multishot, but it just keeps giving me the error code "`* Line 1, Column 2 Missing '}' or object member name`".

One of the commands that I have tried is `/give @p crossbow 1 3 {enchant:[{id:33},{lvl:127]}`.

I am using the pocket edition 1.11.4.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! At the moment we don't have quite enough details to help you. What's the full error message? What version of MCPE are you using? Also please be sure to include your error message and command as text, not just a screenshot. Remember that you can always [edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/352270/edit) to improve your post. Good luck!

Comment: The full error message is "`* Line 1, Column 2 Missing '}' or object member name`" as shown in the image, it is pretty much certainly the latest versions, as you can tell by the dark background of the GUI, I will add that information to the question. The information given is enough to answer the question though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give a player an item with custom properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374643/how-do-i-give-a-player-an-item-with-custom-properties)

Answer (score 2):

**NBT tags have not (yet?) been fully implemented into the pocket edition**

The only implemented tags that I am aware of are "`can_place_on`" and "`can_destroy`", which I did not know until I read [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition), I thought that no tags were implemented yet.

*Note: I have tested some other tags and I could not find any other tags that worked.*

You could do this, but this would replace whatever item you currently have in your main hand. It may not work propperly if you quickly switch between items.

[image: 2 command blocks connected with a 2 tick repeater, one command block has a wooden button]

The right command block has this command

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.weapon.mainhand 0 crossbow 1
```

The left command block has this command:

```
/enchant @p multishot 1
```

*Note 2: The repeater is set to 2 ticks, because 1 tick leads to some really weird behaviour. You cannot set the level of the enchantment "multishot" any higher than 1 in the pocket edition*

Answer (score 1):

You can have a chest with an enchanted crossbow (or any other item) that you clone to the position of the player and then you imidiately destroy the chest by using `/setblock` in a chain command block.

Your setup may look like this:

[image: The set-up with 2 command blocks, a chest, and a button]

The impulse command block clones the chest to the position of the player with this command:

```
/execute <target> ~ ~ ~ clone <chest coordinates> <chest coordinates> ~ ~ ~
```

And the chain command block will set the chest to air, while dropping the item(s) inside:

```
/execute <target> ~ ~ ~ setblock air 0 destroy
```

*Note: Other players may be faster at picking up the item(s), they will simply drop to the floor near the player, they could also fall into lava, or get destroyed, or be lost in a different way.*

*Note 2: If the player is standing on a half slab, or inside of any block, then that block will be set to air, so it may potentially break parts of your map*