# How do I spawn a zombie with the closest player's name MCPE

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I need to have a zombie with the closest player's name but I don't know how to do it anyone that can help? I think it would be something like this: `/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {name:@p}`

Comment: You mean like spawning a zombie by someone with a name most similar to Zombie?

Comment: I believe they mean spawning a Zombie that takes on the name of the closest player.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition) Summoning something with a name requires NBT tags, which are only avaiable on Java Edition.

Comment: **Update:** summoning named entities is now possible, but unfortunately naming something with `@p` still isn't allowed. Check the marked duplicate of this for the link.