# Is there anyway to use the setblock command to when I hold an item in my hand (torch) it places a torch on the ground (bedrock edition)

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Trying to create a dynamic lighting command that when you hold a torch in your hand a torch is placed at the charcters feet and when the torch is not in hand then the torch is no longer at the players feet.

Have been trying for several hours and cant find a solution.

Comment: What are the things you have tried?

Comment: I havent really delved deep into commands yet but ive tried many versions of detect and execute commands. Do you know if there is a string of commands on bedrock that can detect a specific object in a players hand?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to detect holding an item in a player's hand in Bedrock Edition as [there is no NBT](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/188492).