# Using /clear to clear an item with a custom name

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am using Windows 10, version 1.14.1 to make an adventure map. I am trying to clear an item with a custom name from the inventory of a player when they push a button. I can clear generic items perfectly fine, but the custom name always causes a problem.

```
/clear @p paper 0 1 {display:{Name:"Bandages"}}
```

It doesn't work. Is this just something I cannot do on bedrock edition? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Comment: Unfortunately no it does not. Though I can't seem to give an item with a custom name either. I suppose it may not be available in Bedrock edition.

Comment: Yes, that is what the answer over there means: A nice way to say "you can't, play the original instead". ;) It's helpful to look at MCJava and MCBE as what they internally are: Two entirely separate games. Sadly Microsoft's marketing makes them seem more similar than they actually are.