# In Minecraft Bedrock Edition, how would I specify larger, zoomed- out maps in a /clear command

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a pvp survival world on Minecraft BEDROCK EDITION. I don't want players to be able to see where everyone is in a huge area with huge maps, but I also would like it if they could see people just nearby them. I would like to delete the larger maps from their inventory but keep the smaller ones. Is there any way I could differentiate between the map levels/sizes?

Comment: Probable duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Comment: I am pretty sure that's yet another case where you would need NBT checks in commands. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.