# Why can't I /give a renamed 'paper' item in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am attempting to give a player a 'paper' item with the name "left" but it isn't working. This is the command I'm using:

```
/give Fireblade8409 paper 1 0 {display:{Name:"left"}}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Line 1, Column 2
> Missing '}' or object member name

How do I fix this?

[image: command block window]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 0):

NBT tags aren't supported on Bedrock, except CanPlaceOn and CanBreakWith. They said to add support later, but the ETA is "later" for a long time now.