# How could I detect with command blocks when a mob is at a certain health or percentage?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am building a boss fight with multiple waves of enemies. I am trying to figure out how to detect whether an entity (in this case **wither**) so when it's at **2/3** and **1/3** health it spawns more entities such as angry zombie pigmen, blaze, wither skeleton, etc. Is there a way to do this on Minecraft Bedrock or is it really only possible on the Java edition on Minecraft? From what I know you can only use "dummy" scoreboard objectives on Bedrock. All others are only available on Java (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: You probably can't, because NBT commands don't exist. But maybe there's something else that is MCBE specific, I don't know. If structure blocks exist, you could in theory copy the mob, damage it a little many times and count how many times it takes until it dies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: Sorry, I didn't realize this was a bedrock question, this answer is for Java.**

**Note that this will break if more than one boss exists at a time! One of them will likely be prioritised.**

You'll need a scoreboard objective that tracks their health, so make a dummy objective (I'll call it bossHealth) and read the boss's health into that.

```
execute as @e[...] store result score CurHP bossHealth run data get entity @s Health
```

You'll also need to know the boss's max health, which you can read from NBT:

```
execute as @e[...] store result score MaxHP bossHealth run data get entity @s Attributes[0].Base
```

You can then calculate the percentage of health the boss has remaining:

```
scoreboard players operation Percent bossHealth = CurHP bossHealth
scoreboard players set percentTemp bossHealth 100
scoreboard players operation Percent bosshealth *= percentTemp bossHealth
scoreboard players operation Percent bossHealth /= MaxHP bossHealth
scoreboard players reset percentTemp bossHealth
```

You can then do whatever you want with the percentage. If you wanted something to happen when the wither has 2/3 health, then:

```
execute if score Percent bossHealth matches ..67 run [something]
```