# Is it possible to use /summon a tipped arrow in bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to summon an arrow of instant damage 2 in Minecraft bedrock edition, and I cannot figure a way to do it. Is it possible to do this in bedrock? If so, how?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think that you can summon arrows with potion effects in MCBE. In Java, you would use NBT but this doesn't exist in Bedrock Edition.