# Why can't I get player heads in Minecraft on the Xbox One?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play on Xbox One, and I do commands to give heads, like  `/give @s skull 1 3{SkullOwner:MrCrainer}`, but it doesn't work. (MrCrainer was a real player example.)

I don't use internet on Xbox, because it'll force an update that won't work. I have 1.14.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can get player heads in Bedrock edition.

Comment: I've seen people do so though without mods

Comment: You could try to do what they do

Comment: I do what they do. The code is an example of what they put (the username is a real Minecraft username) It is exactly the same.

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message?

Comment: Yes, I do. It says there was an error at the Name I entered.