# How can I /give myself a stone axe that can only break oak signs/planks in Adventure Mode?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to obtain a stone axe that can destroy oak signs and oak planks in Adventure Mode.

The command that I have tried is:

```
/give @p stone_axe 1 0 {can_destroy: {"blocks": ["oak_sign","oak_wood_planks"]}}
```

The error message that I get is:

```
* Line 1, Column 2
Missing '}' or object member name
```

What is the mistake in this command, and what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

/give @p minecraft:stone_axe 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:oak_sign","minecraft:oak_wood_planks"]}

(Ps. It might be wrong I'm not a command expert).

Comment: Nah I play on a switch and every time I do CanDestroy instead of can_destroy it doesn't register. And putting Minecraft in front of it works the same as not putting Minecraft in front of it.

Comment: Aaaaah, I'm such an idiot! I didn't read the tag. Bedrock and Java have very different commands. I forgot about that. I'll see what I can do on my Switch.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to place quotes around `can_destroy`!

```
/give @p stone_axe 1 0 {"can_destroy": {"blocks": ["oak_sign","oak_wood_planks"]}}
```

I would also like to take this opportunity to remind you that Bedrock Edition does not currently support any other tags besides `can_destroy` and `can_place_on`.