# how to get player heads on xbox one 1.14.6

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I am making a map for DanTDM, Logdotzip, etc. and my family. I am only 12 and I have no idea how to do advanced commands I only know basics. So I was wondering how you get player skulls on 1.14.60. I tried this command, /give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:Logdotzip} and others but it didn't work. I am on bedrock.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Comment: I think you need Java edition, maybe PC or iPad BE.

Comment: Note for later: Datapacks in MCJava let you get heads of players without entering any NBT. So when datapack come to MCBE, this might become possible, even if NBT commands still aren't there then.

Answer (score 1):

Having a custom player head is a Java Edition-exclusive feature. There is no way to get a custom player head in Bedrock Edition. If you were to be able to do this, it would require the editing of NBT tags, which is impossible in Bedrock Edition.

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid now but thank you.

Comment: Also one more question. On my version 1.14.60, I know that the can be placed on command is still a thing, but it says it needs to update but I have the latest version of Minecraft. What does it mean?