# How do I summon a horse with specific attributes in Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have done a lot of research on a command to summon a horse with specific attributes (increased health, etc.) but it all is in Java. To me, the Java commands make a lot of sense but the Bedrock commands don't. This is the command I'm trying to execute (it's in Java):

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Tame:1,Variant:9,Attributes:[{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:2},{Name:horse.jumpStrength,Base:7}]},{Health:25.0f},{Invulnerable:1}
```

Can anyone help my confusion and describe/give examples of how to include tags/modify horses in bedrock edition?

---

[Browse more workarounds for getting/setting NBT in Bedrock Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180)

Answer (score 2):

After some more research and personal experimentation, I have concluded that the Bedrock command coding is just not as sophisticated as in the Java edition. Thus, I believe I/we will just have to wait for future updates. I come to this conclusion because, as shown in https://www.digminecraft.com/spawn_events/horse.php, there are very limited coloring/attribute tags. Plus, if you try to spawn a horse that is both black and tame using the command:

```
/summon horse ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:make_black minecraft:on_tame
```

You just get a black horse whose name is: "minecraft:on_tame"

If you try separating the two attributes with a comma:

```
/summon horse ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:make_black,minecraft:on_tame
```

You just get an error message about how it expects whitespace where the comma is.

Thus I conclude that Minecraft Bedrock edition version 1.16.1 is just not capable of the desired command yet.