# Referencing JSON file in Minecraft Bedrock via command

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

On Minecraft Bedrock Edition, I have just created a JSON file that creates a chest with random loot in it. The problem is that I don't know the command to get the chest that contains random loot. Here is what I did.

I used https://minecraft.tools/en/loots.php to create a loot table that gives you a certain amount of random items.

I then saved this in a JSON file and put it in the following directory along with a manifest JSON file in order for Minecraft to recognise it.

[image]

The problem I am now having is that I don't know how to use the give command in Minecraft to give me a chest with random loot that uses the JSON file. The website I used to create the random loot table generator mentions this is the command you would use to get the chest with random loot from the JSON file loot table created (in Java Editon though):

```
/give @p minecraft:chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{LootTable:"mctools:chests/loot_table"}}
```

The problems I am having with this are that I don't know what directory I would need to put in to access the JSON file loot table, I am also not sure what other syntax would be needed because I know the idea of using minecraft:chest only works for Minecraft: Java Edition and for Minecraft: Bedrock Edition you would have to do something different. What I am asking is, what type of command do I need to use to give me a chest which uses the JSON file loot table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Comment: @pppery It seems to me that this problem indeed prevents the use of the above command. It was only included as an example of what the asker wanted though. The question remains valid: is there an alternative?

Comment: You may find You may find https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/fiv76g/bedrock_edition_commands_to_spawn_a_loot_table/ a useful resource. to be a useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

The loot tables determine spoils of randomly generated dungeon loot, but don't give you a way to spawn them directly.

A better way of doing this is to fill several chests with loot load-outs. You can then copy these chests by Ctrl+pick-block to duplicate them. This will allow you to place them in a dispenser or dropper and have them dispensed to the player. The player can then place them down themselves to retrieve the items.

Comment: What are load-outs?

Comment: A chest loaded with loot. Basically, make a chest for each loot table you wanted. You can then do the ctrl+pick block to duplicate the chest as an item. These could be give to a player.

Answer (score -1):

The location you would specify the loot table in Minecraft Java Edition is in the NBT tags. Notice how the command the website gave you is only for Java Edition. In Bedrock, you come across a roadblock: you [can't specify NBT](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180). If you click on the link, you can see that there *are* some workarounds, but unfortunately there aren't any for loot tables.

Therefore, you couldn't possibly be able to give yourself a chest with a loot table using commands, because there is no place to specify it.

Comment: How come I could add it in as a resource pack?

Comment: @DigitalRookie4 What do you mean? Could you elaborate on exactly what you did?

Comment: I created the loot_table as a JSON file and when I put it in the resources folder minecraft found it.

Comment: @DigitalRookie4 But how would you be able to reference that loot table in your `/give` command?

Comment: Ok, I might have not mentioned I am trying to get a chest that has random loot spawned into it when placed (the code for it is a JSON file). Also, I believe the loot table is needed to link minecraft to the JSON file or something like that.

Comment: @DigitalRookie4 Then my answer most certainly applies. Read it - your problem does not have a solution.

Comment: Any way of converting a bedrock world to Java or a way of creating chests that generate random loot? :(

Comment: @DigitalRookie4 I don't know off the top of my head, but you can certainly search online, search Arqade using the search box at the top, or wait for the next answer.

Comment: What about this then? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Llz-BihClx8

Comment: @DigitalRookie4 Yeah, but that uses external programs. I thought you just wanted commands.

Comment: I want to try to find a way to place these loot tables into a chest in any way at all.