# Can someone tell me what im doing wrong in minecraft command

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image: give @p lever 1 0{display:{Name:"Key"}}]

What does it mean when it says line 1, Column 2 missing) or object member name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, NBT data for entities or items is not currently supported for the Bedrock edition. This kind of thing will not be possible for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score -1):

Quoted directly from [How do you add NBT tags to commands in minecraft pocket bedrock edition:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

> Unfortunately, this is not possible in PE or BE (Bedrock Edition) except for the "can_place_on" or "can_destroy" tag:

However, if you really want to have a lever named "Key", I'd suggest you rename it manually using an anvil.