# How to get a permanently invisible armor stand without cheats

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to create some armor stand art in my Hermitcraft-style world, but I am not sure how to do it. I have seen ZombieCleo do it on Java Edition, but I am playing on Bedrock Edition and don't know how to turn armor stands permanently invisible. Is there a way to do this without cheats?

Comment: Did ZombieCleo do it without cheats on Java Edition? If they used cheats, then it could be the only way.

Comment: I'm not sure. I am using Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 2):

I have no way to verify this (I don't play on Bedrock Edition), but this seems to be one of those things that isn't possible in Bedrock Edition because of the [lack of support for most NBT data](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/334104/1351).  You need to set the `Invisble` tag to true, but that tag doesn't exist in Bedrock Edition.  Additionally, in Bedrock Edition you're [limited in what poses are available for armour stands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor_Stand#Usage), whereas in Java Edition you can pose each limb individually.