# How do you create a CanDestroy tag with a block requiring a data value?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I create a CanDestroy tag in such a way that only Cracked Stone Bricks can be destroyed.
Im on Bedrock 1.16 for ps4. The code is this:
`/give @p stone_pickaxe 1 0 {"Minecraft:can_destroy":["blocks":["98:2"]}}`

Either the answer or the item id (the thing needed) for cracked stone bricks would help.
Thanks in advance

Edit: People have been suggesting [This question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition) The question there asks how to add nbt data such as lore or enchantments. This is different from what I'm asking. Im asking how to make a pickaxe that can only destroy a certain block which has data value. The reason the data value is important is because in bedrock stonebrick has 4 options: 0 - normal, 1 - mossy, 2 - cracked and 3 - Chisled. I'm asking how to add a data value of 2 to the block id  in the CanDestroy tag

TLDR: How to add data value to blocks inside a CanDestroy Tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Comment: No, its id. The actual command itself works. I need to know how to nbt to the canDestroy tag block so that i can point out that I mean **Cracked Stone Bricks** but not normal stone bricks. The link you gave is useful, just not for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to specify data values in `can_place_on` or `can_destroy`. Cracked stone bricks are just the `stonebrick` block ID with the data value 2.

You can try using the infested stone bricks, they are actually different blocks under the ID `monster_egg`. These use the same data values, but they're able to be differentiated with block ID. Just remember, don't use monster egg blocks as ones that can be broken!

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_data_value using find in page for "cracked" and the only results were 'cracked_nether_bricks' and 'cracked_polished_blackstone_bricks'.
Try `/give @p stone_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:cracked_stone_bricks"]} 1` , which is the java command. If that doesn't work, I don't think that it's possible.