# How do I give myself a potion or tipped arrow with an effect?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Java Edition, I can give myself a potion with effect with an NBT tag:

```
give @s potion 1 0 {Potion:"minecraft:regeneration"}
```

However, I cannot do this in Bedrock Edition, as there is no access to NBT tags from commands.

How can I give myself a status effect potion with the `/give` command?

---

[Browse more workarounds for getting/setting NBT in Bedrock Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bedrock Edition uses data values to store the potion effect used by a potion or Tipped Arrow. To give a potion of tipped arrow with the specified effect, you use the command:

```
give <player> potion <data value>
```

Here is a table for the data values for potions:

| Potion | Regular | Extended | Enhanced |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Water Bottle | 0 | ― | ― |
| Mundane Potion | 1 | 2 | ― |
| Thick Potion | 3 | ― | ― |
| Awkward Potion | 4 | ― | ― |
| Potion of Night Vision | 5 | 6 | ― |
| Potion of Invisibility | 7 | 8 | ― |
| Potion of Leaping | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| Potion of Fire Resistance | 12 | 13 | ― |
| Potion of Swiftness | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| Potion of Slowness | 17 | 18 | **42** |
| Potion of Water Breathing | 19 | 20 | ― |
| Potion of Healing | 21 | ― | 22 |
| Potion of Harming | 23 | ― | 24 |
| Potion of Poison | 25 | 26 | 27 |
| Potion of Regeneration | 28 | 29 | 30 |
| Potion of Strength | 31 | 32 | 33 |
| Potion of Weakness | 34 | 35 | ― |
| Potion of Decay | 36 | ― | ― |
| Potion of the Turtle Master | 37 | 38 | 39 |
| Potion of Slow Falling | 40 | 41 | ― |

For tipped arrows, use this similar command:

```
give <player> arrow <data value>
```

The table of data values for tipped arrows is shown below. Note that the ID is just `arrow`, and not `tipped_arrow` like in Java Edition. The data values are also one larger than those for potions.

| Arrow | Regular | Extended | Enhanced |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arrow | 0 | ― | ― |
| Arrow of Splashing | 1 | ― | ― |
| Tipped Arrow (Mundane) | 2 | 3 | ― |
| Tipped Arrow (Thick) | 4 | ― | ― |
| Tipped Arrow (Awkward) | 5 | ― | ― |
| Arrow of Night Vision | 6 | 7 | ― |
| Arrow of Invisibility | 8 | 9 | ― |
| Arrow of Leaping | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| Arrow of Fire Resistance | 13 | 14 | ― |
| Arrow of Swiftness | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| Arrow of Slowness | 18 | 19 | **43** |
| Arrow of Water Breathing | 20 | 21 | ― |
| Arrow of Healing | 22 | ― | 23 |
| Arrow of Harming | 24 | ― | 25 |
| Arrow of Poison | 26 | 27 | 28 |
| Arrow of Regeneration | 29 | 30 | 31 |
| Arrow of Strength | 32 | 33 | 34 |
| Arrow of Weakness | 35 | 36 | ― |
| Arrow of Decay | 37 | ― | ― |
| Arrow of the Turtle Master | 38 | 39 | 40 |
| Arrow of Slow Falling | 41 | 42 | ― |

These tables are a transcription of those on the Minecraft Wiki, for [potions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Metadata) and [arrows](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Arrow#Data_values) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is no need for an NBT here to give a potion.

You just need the data value for the item:

```
/give @a potion 1 7
```

Here is a table of data values for the potions.

[image: Potion Table]