# How to get potions by /give in V1.17.10 Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need this for my Minecraft map, I tried /give @s potion_of_weakness and it didn't work.

Comment: Here is our already-made guide on that matter: [How do I give myself a potion or tipped arrow with an effect?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374591/how-do-i-give-myself-a-potion-or-tipped-arrow-with-an-effect)

Answer (score 0):

Bedrock edition has something called data value. You have to put /give @s potion and the corresponding potion data value. Here are a list of them https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Bedrock_Edition