# How do I summon a baby mob?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft Java Edition, one can summon baby zombies and drowned using the `IsBaby` NBT tag:

```
/summon zombie X Y Z {IsBaby:1b}
```

Likewise, one can summon baby breedable mobs (Pigs, Cows, etc.) by giving them a negative `Age` NBT tag (the number of ticks until the mob grows up):

```
/summon cow X Y Z {Age:-100000}
```

Since NBT is inaccessible from commands in Bedrock Edition, the above commands will not work there.

How do I summon baby mobs in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a baby mob by applying the appropriate [spawn event](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_event) in the `/summon` command.

For drowned and zombies, it is `minecraft:as_baby`, and for other mobs, it is `minecraft:entity_born`.

To summon a baby zombie or drowned:

```
/summon <zombie/drowned> X Y Z minecraft:as_baby
```

And to summon a baby animal:

```
/summon <entity type> X Y Z minecraft:entity_born
```

This does not work with villagers due to a [bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-61976).

Comment: Baby Zombies and drowned never age, and baby villagers and animals do grow up. I don't think any of this varies depending on edition or even whether they were created with commands.