# How to summon a baby villager in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to summon a baby villager in Minecraft Bedrock Edition, but my command isn't working because it summons a regular villager instead of a baby villager.

I used the commands based off of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374618/250180) post, which is listed below, but it doesn't work.

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ minecraft:entity_born
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I summon a baby mob?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374618/how-do-i-summon-a-baby-mob)

Comment: Questions with incorrect answers do not cease to be valid duplicate targets.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [unresolved, confirmed bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-61976). Unfortunately, unless you are able to find an add-on to work around this issue, you will just have to wait for a fix to come out.

If you believe that this is an important issue, consider voting for the bug via the link above, or start watching it to know when updates are made.

Comment: I can't download an add-on or mod.

Comment: @FreePlayer Then wait for it to be fixed.