# How do I summon a villager with a certain profession?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft Java Edition, you can specify the profession of a villager you summon using the `VillagerData` NBT tag. For example, the below command spawns a librarian villager:

```
/summon villager X Y Z {VillagerData:{Profession:"minecraft:librarian"}}
```

Since NBT does not exist in Bedrock Edition, the above commands will not work there.

How do I summon a villager with a certain profession in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished in Bedrock Edition using spawn events. For example, you use the `minecraft:spawn_librarian` spawn event to summon a librarian villager:

```
/summon villager X Y Z minecraft:spawn_librarian
```

Spawn events also exist for farmers (`minecraft:spawn_farmer`), clerics (`minecraft:spawn_cleric`), armorers (`minecraft:spawn_armorer`), and butchers (`minecraft:spawn_butcher`). See [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_event) for a complete list of spawn events.