# How do I get an Arctic fox in a flat bedrock or Minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I get an Arctic fox in a flat bedrock or Minecraft world

Please make sure it works on iOS

Comment: Hello, may I know which version is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition) You can't get an arctic fox in a flat Bedrock edition world because you can't change the biome of the world and you can't change the type of the fox.