# How do i get a Snow fox in minecraft ps4. i have tried commands and they don't work

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have tried several commands but none work. Please help, it's for ps4 in a realm
I have googled it and watched vids but nothing i have found works, please help me

Comment: Please provide the commands you were using.

Comment: Are you even in a snow biome?

Comment: Possibly Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/376181/258509

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get a snow fox in bedrock is to use a spawn egg in a snowy biome (meaning it's impossible to do it in a flat world because you need to be in the actual biome, you can't just place snow). Once you have successfully spawned one, you could use a structure block to save the fox entity to a structure and then spawn it in via the structure command.

Comment: note that there's no "structure command", but hey +1 thats a really clever technique

Comment: There is indeed a structure command: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/structure though it is bedrock exclusive at the moment.

Comment: Oh I didn't even know about that cool feature! Sorry, thanks that's useful tho