# How can I get NBT data from a specific block?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to recreate some "Custom NBT Data's", but I can't seem to figure out how.

I'm looking for something like:

```
Items:[0:{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:sandstone",Count:1b,Damage:0s}]
```

Is there a way to access this in Bedrock edition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test for a chest with items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376620/how-can-i-test-for-a-chest-with-items)

Comment: nbt is unavailable on bedrock