# How do I make a custom potion with MCBE add-ons/behaviour packs?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

How do I make a custom potion with Minecraft addons?

I have seen others do it (at MCPEDL, which is a site that you can post addons, resource packs, and maps).

I don't want to make a "potion" crafted at a crafting table, which isn't really a potion, and is counted as a food.

This is not similar to this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376629/262686) because that requires command blocks, I would like to use add-ons/behavior packs.

Comment: This seems like a pretty simple question to me, what's unclear? (for close-voters)

Comment: This is not simillar, because that requires command blocks. I want to do custom potions with addons. Not command blocks!

Comment: Then you have to specify in your question that you don't want command blocks - it just happens to be an answer to your question. Asking for recommendations for add-ons is also off-topic.

Comment: @joachim where do I ask about making addons?

Comment: Vote to reopen please because: **ADDONS vs COMMANDS.** Not the same. Please inspect the ***tags*** first before closing at the very least because I'm still not sure what part is being confused. They are both requesting different methods, and he isn't asking for either-or he wants a specific one.

Comment: Jmooroof: you don't. And I didn't suggest you do. @Penguin That's a good point - I didn't notice as it wasn't explicated in the proposed duplicate question (and apparently failed to look at the tags).

Comment: @Penguin Leave closed for now. Must be discussed first: [Are MCBE behaviour packs considered mods](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15948/250180)? (if result indicates behaviour packs *are* mods, this question should stay closed, with an invalid close reason but a comment indicating the correct close reason.)

Comment: you want a potion that just like any other potion is created in a brewing stand and gives some form of effect on consumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.20.30 (not sure about earlier versions), it **is possible** to add custom potions with a Minecraft Addon, which are craftable with the **brewing stand**. The recipe should be tagged with `"tags": ["brewing_stand"]` instead of `"tags": ["crafting_table"]`.

The Bedrock Wiki has documentation on brewing recipes here (scroll to the bottom of the page): https://wiki.bedrock.dev/loot/recipes.html

Implementing a functional custom potion requires multiple files to be set up in your addon's resource and behavior packs. So, I've linked a [downloadable demo pack](https://www.mediafire.com/file/bqfo02vlktmvf2j/Custom_Potion_Addon_updated.zip/file) (on MediaFire) which you can use as a template for your own custom potions.

---

*To avoid having a link-only answer, here is an overview of what's in the template addon:*

The custom **Potion of Anchoring** sets the player's spawn point to the location where the potion is consumed, only if the player is standing on a solid block in the Overworld. The functionality is accomplished using server-side scripting (tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/scriptingintroduction?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable, reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/minecraft-server?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable), but if you don't want to use this in your addon, you might use item events (documentation here: https://wiki.bedrock.dev/items/items-16.html) as an alternative.

The potion item itself is made consumable using the `"minecraft:food"` component, but note that it does not give nutrition/saturation points, and can be consumed even if the player's hunger bar is full. When used, it plays the `"drink"` (not `"eat"`) animation. So, even though the custom potion is *technically* a food item, I believe it still should satisfy OP's requirement of being a "real" potion.

**BP/items/potion_of_anchoring.item.json**

```
{  
  "format_version": "1.20.30",  
  "minecraft:item": {  
        "description": {  
            "identifier": "template:potion_of_anchoring",  
            "menu_category": {  
                // Make the potion findable next to the other (vanilla) potions
                "category": "equipment",
                "group": "itemGroup.name.potion"
            }  
        },  
        "components": {         
            "minecraft:max_stack_size": 1,
            // This is the color used for rare items like the Enchanted Golden Apple
            "minecraft:hover_text_color": "light_purple",
            "minecraft:glint": true, // Gives it that shimmering effect that all the useful potions have
            "minecraft:icon": {  
                "texture": "potion_of_anchoring"  
            },  
            "minecraft:display_name": {  
                "value": "Potion of Anchoring"  
            },
            // This component is only present so that the custom potion item becomes consumable.
            // The potion does not give nutrition/saturation points, ignores the player being full,
            // and has its effects applied entirely by server-side scripting.
            "minecraft:food": {
                "nutrition": 0,
                "saturation_modifier": 0,
                "can_always_eat": true,
                "using_converts_to": "minecraft:glass_bottle"
            },
            // Here is a reference for the different animations: https://wiki.bedrock.dev/items/items-intro.html
            "minecraft:use_animation": "drink",
            "minecraft:use_duration": 2 // 2 seconds
        }
    }
}
```

**BP/recipes/anchoring_potion.item.json**

```
{
    "format_version": "1.20.30",
    // Reference (scroll to the bottom of the page for brewing stand recipes): https://wiki.bedrock.dev/loot/recipes.html
    "minecraft:recipe_brewing_mix": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "template:anchoring_potion"
        },
        "tags": ["brewing_stand"],
        "input": "minecraft:potion", // A vanilla water bottle
        "reagent": "minecraft:obsidian",
        "output": "template:potion_of_anchoring"
    }
}
```

**RP/textures/item_texture.json**

```
{
    "resource_pack_name": "customPotionRP",
    "texture_name": "atlas.items",
    "texture_data": {
        "potion_of_anchoring": {
            "textures": "textures/items/potion_of_anchoring"
        }
    }
}
```

**BP/scripts/main.js**

```
import { world, system } from "@minecraft/server"

// Useful Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/minecraft-server?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable

// Use Custom Potion: Potion of Anchoring -- Sets player's spawn point to the block you're currently standing on
world.afterEvents.itemCompleteUse.subscribe(event => {
    // Not "itemUse", "itemCompleteUse"! This is important if you don't want the effect to happen until the item is consumed.
    if (event.itemStack.typeId === "template:potion_of_anchoring") {
        const player = event.source;
        const d = player.dimension;
        
        // Only set the player's spawn point to the current location if the player is in the Overworld and is standing on a solid block
        if (d.id === "minecraft:overworld" && player.isOnGround) {
            var at = player.location;
            
            (async () => {
                // Generate spawnpoint command for the player having consumed the potion, at the block on which the potion was consumed, using string concatenation
                await d.runCommandAsync("spawnpoint " + player.name + " " + Math.round(at.x) + " " + Math.round(at.y) + " " + Math.round(at.z));
            })();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Edited the BP `.json` file so that consuming the custom potion now leaves an empty glass bottle behind in the player's inventory, the same as for vanilla potions.