# How can I give an effect if the player is wearing a certain type of boots?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I make an effect run if a player is wearing a certain type of boots? Is there a detection system for this?

Comment: I think I might have a system that detects if they are wearing **any boots at all**. Would you be interested in hearing that? What you asked for specifically is not to my knowledge at all possible.

Comment: Also, don’t worry if it is tagged bedrock edition it will get answers for bedrock. I have suggested an edit, but know in the future that your answers will be about bedrock, and we know many people use bedrock. That’s why that tag exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Comment: @Penguin What is your suggestion? Is it the `/clear` with max count 0 method, or something else?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I'd have to try it, but I was thinking something like with the `replaceitem` command and replacing for air. It would be not very good, and I think yours actually sounds much better with the only downside being all they have to do is hold it

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 if that works it would definitely be better than mine, that could probably be an answer to the question. Of course the only downside being instead of "certain type" being a name or something, it would have to be a material