# Is there a command in Minecraft Bedrock Edition that can repair your armor and weapons to their full health?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am interested in growing my knowledge of commands and would find something like this very useful.

Comment: no. this would be nbt iirc, something inaccessible in bedrock

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition) (per Topcode's comment)

Answer (score 2):

While you can't directly repair them, you can do things such as

```
replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head 0 diamond_helemt
```

but I'm afraid that's the closest you can get and that only really works if you know what they're wearing in the first place.