# In Minecraft Bedrock Edition, is it possible to use commands to give yourself a custom spawner that spawns empty glass bottles?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make an automatic potion brewer that constantly brews potions, and I came across the question “Where can I get an infinite supply of empty bottles?” My first though was a custom spawner, but I don’t know if you can customize a spawner with commands. If it is possible, can somebody reply with the command(s) to either give a custom spawner or modify an already placed spawner. I am on BEDROCK Edition.

Comment: on bedrock, i dont think so. on java, still not sure but maybe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition)