# How can I clear an item with a custom name?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've read all the same questions already but mine is in Bedrock, not Java, so.
I need a command to clear one item custom named from my inventory. I've already tried `clear @p [type=light_block] 1` and `kill @e [type=item, name="$100"] 1`  but it doesn't work. I'm using Minecraft PE Bedrock 1.16.201

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 1):

You can do items with a certain ID or data. For example, clear a yellow concrete block:

```
/clear @p concrete 4
```

If you have a certain block from an addon, you can still use it in the clear command:

```
/clear @p myprefix:light_block
```

Another thing you can do is give the player a normally unobtainable item, such as a top smooth stone slab:

```
/clear @p stone_slab 8
```

Or something that you wouldn’t normally use in game like a clock:

```
/clear @p clock
```

Using names for clearing isn’t possible.