# Why isn't this give command with a display name working?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

I don’t understand how to fix this or what this error means.

Comment: That would simply cause false hope and be of no benefit to anyone.

Comment: @Penguin That isn't the right duplicate to address the issue of the syntax error. Look at the error, and notice that it points to the item ID, not the NBT. Is there yet a Q&A saying you must omit the namespace (`minecraft:`) in writing item IDs? That is the correct duplicate, if it does not exist, this should be left open and answered with that fact, with talk about the NBT issue as a *minor footnote*. Because the main issue presented here is the namespace issue, we should not judge secondary issues when marking duplicates.

Comment: @pppery I have changed my stance. Instead of addressing the main issue only and addressing the NBT issue later, we can address them both in one, by talking about the namespace issue first and foremost and talking about the NBT further down, see my new comment above. I still disagree with marking this as a duplicate of the BE NBT question because it's not the primary issue the image is depicting. At this point, we can: **A:** Find a duplicate talking about the namespace issue. **B:** Create one if it does not exist and mark this as duplicate. **C:** Leave this open and make it the canonical.

Comment: @Penguin I would suggest option A or B in my above comment to pppery. Option C does not seem viable as this question already includes other errors in it, a canonical should focus on the singular issue only.

Comment: Ummm so no help ‍♀️

Comment: @Yohanna this is just plain impossible, we can't give you much help. Right now there's an argument on what to do with this question but we all agree that this isn't *directly* possible (there are some workarounds)

Comment: @Penguin My comment about false hope was a response to a since-deleted comment by ExpertCoder14, not to you

Comment: @pppery okay, sorry it was a bit confusing w/o the @

Answer (score 5):

The command you got was a Java Edition only command. This will not be able to work because Bedrock Edition has a drastically different command format.

The issue you found in your image was one of the differences. Unlike JE, BE *prohibits* namespace values like `minecraft:` in item names. You must remove them, and also `player_head` is invalid, the correct ID is `skull`:

```
give @p skull
```

Additionally, the stuff in curly brackets `{display:{Name:'…'}}` is called NBT, which allows you to set specific item properties. Bedrock Edition commands [do not have access to NBT](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180), so you are unable to set custom player skulls in that edition.

In the future, please be wary whether the source that you are getting your commands from is a Java Edition source or a Bedrock Edition source. Commands for one edition will most certainly not work on the other.

Comment: not to mention `player_head` doesn't exist anyway, the closest we have is skulls and thats just a steve