# Is it possible to "un-charge" a creeper?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know how to charge a creeper by summoning lightning on top of it:

[image: Screenshot of a charged creeper.]

I've reviewed the vanilla behavior for the creeper, and it is easy to see how a creeper becomes charged:

```
"minecraft:damage_sensor": {
  "triggers": {
    "on_damage": {
      "filters": { "test": "is_family", "subject": "other", "value": "lightning"
      },
      "event": "minecraft:become_charged"
    },
    "deals_damage": false
  }
}
```

However, I've been unable to locate anything similar to the `minecraft:become_charged` event, in order to effectively *un-charge* it.

---

Is it possible to *un-charge* a creeper?

Comment: I also just did some research on it, came to the same conclusion you did, that the only event for it is "become_charged". I won't leave this as an answer as I am not sure how to do it in Bedrock, but a possible solution is just to swap out this creeper with another one that is uncharged. Edit: This [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition) references some of the same language, this may not be possible in Bedrock like it is in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pretty easily:

```
execute @e[type=creeper,tag="Creepers To Change"] ~ ~ ~ summon creeper
tp @e[type=creeper,tag="Creepers To Change"] ~ -100 ~
kill @e[type=creeper,tag="Creepers To Change"]
```

and that would swap them out. Beware they won't have the same names or tags. Swap out the `tag="Creepers To Change"` for any selector arguments of your choice.