# How do I remove armor stand arms on MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play Minecraft Pocket Edition (Bedrock Edition) and I'm trying to do some Java builds. I need to remove the arms of the armor stands, but I can't find a command for it. Does anyone know a command to remove armor stand arms?

Comment: i dont think you can do that without addons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition)