# How to get out of a 1x1x2 space occupied by villager?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm stuck in a 1 x 1 x 2 space with a roof and a villager that takes up the whole area. How can I get out?

I have no pearls, and can't mine out without hitting the villager. I can not use a boat or bed since I can't place blocks or interact with them because of the villager hit box; I would just kill them, but they have a mending trade that took me forever to get.
Is there any way I can get out without the help of another player?

Comment: Any chance of a picture of your current predicament?

Comment: Quite the predicament you found yourself in indeed. I'm afraid there is no good solution unless you have a waterbucket or elytra + rockets or jumpboost on you (and even then - you said it has a roof, so you're not gonna be able to fly / swim out). You'll probably have to accept that you either need someone else to help you or kill the villager.

Comment: Is there a command you can use to simply kill yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this is a very open question, but can't you just get out by breaking the blocks? I realize you said you will hit the villager if you mine, but a villager can take more than one hit!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using another device, or another instance of Bedrock edition to join the world and rescue your player from the cage? If you really want, NBT editing is an option but that kind of violates the survival experience by cheating. On Windows you can enable multiple instances for UWP containers but it's not super easy to explain, so if you have a phone you should try using that.

Comment: Doesn't bedrock edition not support NBT? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition

Comment: It's not about "support" since I doubt Mojang will ever officially support any sort of editing, it's about if people put the effort into creating software that can do what the game's code does to edit the saves. I have had NBT editing tools that work for Bedrock eidition for as long as I can remember, since Bedrock's save files are actually very similar to Java. I used to have tools like MCC ToolChest PE but that seems to have vanished, now you have software as [Universal Minecraft Editor](https://www.universalminecrafttool.com/), which basically the same thing, you should try it out!