# How do you enchant an item while using the /replaceitem command in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a player always have an Elytra on them using `/replaceitem entity @a[Tag=Flight] slot.armor.chest 0 minecraft:elytra 1 0 {"item_lock": {"mode": "lock_in_slot"}}`. But i'm having an issue when the player dies and the item gets dropped, so I want to enchant it with vanishing. How would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition)