# How do I test for a dropped item’s data in Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have an emerald with the data 3. I want to detect it using `/execute @e`.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition)