# How do I fill a specific area with lava filled dispensers?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am building a prison in Minecraft Bedrock Edition. For this, I am trying to place several lava-filled dispensers at once. What would the fill command be for this? Keep in mind, I am on bedrock edition.

Comment: If NBT commands still don't exist in MCBE, this can't be done easily. But maybe some system could be made where you fill one layer with dispensers, then the one above with hoppers, then the one above with water, teleport a player around with a stack of ≥2 buckets and a full inventory who holds sneak+use. A bit ridiculous, but that's the best I can come up with.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition)

Comment: @pppery in the [accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/334104/163757) on the proposed duplicate, in the "currently impossible" section, do any of those items listed cover this? Or should this use case be added there? "Filling" seems to be a commonly asked about question I think here