# How can I get items with custom enchantments on Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am using command blocks and the code I put in is right, for the most part. The command is:

```
/give @p netherite_sword 1 0 {enchantments:{Minecraft:sharpness:255
```

...and it says that is right but if I try to put any brackets to finish it, it says it is wrong but it also says it is wrong without them. Is there anything else I should put?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 1):

## There Isn't Really a Way to Add Custom Enchantments on Vanilla Bedrock Edition

...However, there are two ways that I have thought of:

- You can use the `/execute` command and check to see if someone is holding a certain item and give them a status effect until they aren't holding it anymore, as shown.

### Example

```
execute as @a[s1000, hasitem={item=diamond_sword,location=slot.weapon.mainhand}] at @s run /effect @s 1 25 true
```

Or, you can also do this (and this is honestly the easiest way in my opinion):

- Use a Behavior Pack and make your custom enchantments from there (there are many types of Behavior packs that you could use; just choose one that suits you the most.).

---

Overall, even though there isn't a simple way to do this, there are many loopholes that you can use, and there are many options to choose from.

## Sources